# Is it possible to listen audio via telephone hole?

Tags: audio, loudspeaker

When speaking phone I can listen audio both via small ear hole and via loud speaker. But when I am playing audio like in web page I hear it only loud. Is it possible to pass sound via ear hole in second case too?

If not then why (design explanation required)?